# nginx set directive not working

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm facing the same issue as described in [How to force nginx to resolve DNS (of a dynamic hostname) everytime when doing proxy_pass?](https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p#) and thus wanted to apply the same solution.

My NginX, version 1.15.2, config now looks like this:

```
server {
resolver 127.0.0.1;
set $backend "http://dynamic.example.com:80";
proxy_pass $backend;
}
```

Upon starting, I see the following error message

> [emerg] 11#11: invalid number of arguments in "set" directive in
>   /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:3

Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure there's actually a semicolon after the `set` directive? This kind of error usually means a missing ';' at the end of the line.

Comment: Yep, this is a direct copy/paste

Comment: I have the same issue. (see my last question). I'm also using envstub during nginx startup (but for the value which I set so: set $backend "http://$URL"; (where URL is set bij envstub). Any idea on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nginx config itself was indeed correct.

The problem I had was envsubst also replacing the $backend variable with an empty space.

Comment: Can you add how you were doing the envstub

Comment: I need the envstub but also the variable

Comment: found the solution here: https://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf